# Shopping cart PHP framework

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, ecommerce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Ecommerce Script Should I Use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30150/which-ecommerce-script-should-i-use)

I am going to build a new shopping cart project for my client and I have a little confusion about shopping cart framework in php. I have read about more shopping cart framework, but I can't get the right way to use a perfect framework for my project.

The requirement of the project is:

```
Inventory management
Authorization
UPS shipping integration
```

Please anyone help me out to choose the right frame work and start my project as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My work experience tells me that you should go with "Virtue Mart" for Joomla. 
 or "wp-ecommerce" for Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

The best cart solution I've used is by far OpenCart, it has a lot of functionality and a lot of implementable plug-ins, and the majority of carts, including OpenCart tend to have shipping functionality inbuilt.

Answer (score 0):

**www.magentocommerce.com**

Is, simply put, the **best** you can possibly do today.

The free community version is absolutely brimming with features. Be prepared for a heavy dose of php mvc, however, if you need any customizations. It is, frankly, a very large and complicated system - but a basic install isn't any more difficult to set up than wordpress.

Cheers

Comment: How can it be the best and be complicated at the same time?